# JSON.parse SyntaxError: Unexpected token { while parsing file with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm having problems trying to parse a file that has the following text in it:

```
{ "type": "header", "log_level": 3, "target_port": 80, "source_port_first": 32768, "source_port_last": 61000, "max_targets": -1, "max_runtime": 0, "max_results": 0, "iface": "en0", "rate": 0, "bandwidth": 0, "cooldown_secs": 8, "senders": 7, "use_seed": 0, "seed": 0, "generator": 0, "packet_streams": 1, "probe_module": "tcp_synscan", "output_module": "json", "gw_mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00", "source_ip_first": "127.0.0.1", "source_ip_last": "127.0.0.1", "output_filename": ".\/static\/results\/80.json", "whitelist_filename": ".\/static\/whitelist.conf", "dryrun": 0, "summary": 0, "quiet": 1, "recv_ready": 0 }
{ "type": "result", "saddr": "127.0.0.1" }
```

This is a Zmap output and node.js keeps choking on everything after the first line. If you remove the second line from the file, there are no errors and the program runs fine.

I want to be able to read the JSON data in the file and be able to reference each key and value and print them out in console.log.

Here's my current code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = './80.json';
var bufferString;

function ReadFile(callback) {
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    bufferString = data;
    callback();
  }); 
}

function PrintLine() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(bufferString));
}

ReadFile(PrintLine)
```

Realistically, I would like to put all this data into a database, but I need to solve the problem of reading the file properly.

Comment: Is that exact contents of `80.json`? Because if so, it's not valid JSON hence the error http://jsonlint.com/ . Do you have access to this file?

Comment: That is not valid JSON, because that are _two_ JSON strings in one file. You can probably read them one by one, if you split at the newline first.

Comment: You mean the file has multiple lines, each with an object? Define "chokes".

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that there is always one object per line, just pass each line to `JSON.parse`, not the while file. But I would not name that file `.json` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned, the JSON is invalid. But, instead of turning the JSON in the file into an array of objects, you can also process each line, if each object is on a new line:

*However, be aware that, like @jsve pointed out, your file would then remain a `JSON` impostor.*

```
function PrintLine() {
    var lines = bufferString.split('\n'),
        tmp = [],
        len = lines.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Check if the line isn't empty
        if(lines[i]) tmp.push( JSON.parse(lines[i]) );
    }
    lines = tmp;
    console.log(lines[0], lines[1]);
}

ReadFile(PrintLine);
```

Comment: But then the file wouldn't technically be JSON.

Comment: Well, that's right. Then the file wouldn't be deserving of its `.json` extension, but I think doing such a thing might be helpful if the file is auto-generated.

Comment: The auto-generation logic should probably be changed in that case... but it would not be constructive to continue discussing that in the comments :).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple JSON objects in a file like that. If you want to store 2 objects in JSON you need to add them to an array:

```
[
    { "type": "header", ..., "recv_ready": 0 },
    { "type": "result", "saddr": "127.0.0.1" }
]
```

You can access each object with their index:

```
var json = JSON.parse(bufferString);
json[0]; // this is the first object (defined on the first line)
json[1]; // this is the second object (defined on the second line)
```